# Command Prompt not working correctly

Tags: command, environment-variables, command-prompt

Every time I install a new program that uses command prompt it still does not recognize it.  For example, I have installed `git` and `nodejs` and added them to the `%PATH%`, but they are still unrecognizable in my command prompt.

`%Path% = C:\Program Files (x86)\WANdisco\Subversion;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs`

If any other system variables need to be posted, let me know!  Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I think instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd` your path should contain `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin`. Probably similar problem with `nodejs`.

Comment: This did not work.  I still get the unrecognizable error message.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

```
 %Path% =
```

Use this:

```
 Path=
```

and it will be modified for the scope of the batch file.

To make it global so it is available in every cmd prompt you can use `SETX` or modify the Windows environment variables in control panel, system, advanced.